# How do we apply auto incremented grouping id for each grouped partition in spark RDD?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

My requirement

Add a new column to an existing dataframe named interval_id

Once we see a record with event_type as "PART" For a (same event_start_date_time and service_key ) then the next records onwards needs to be auto incremented

My Input(sample) :

```scala
---------------------+-----------+------------+--------------+
|event_start_date_time|service_key|  event_type|event_sequence|
+---------------------+-----------+------------+--------------+
| 2017-12-30T11:00:00Z|       1832|     SPONSOR|           280|
| 2017-12-30T11:00:00Z|       1832|        PART|           281|
| 2017-12-30T11:00:00Z|       1832|     SPONSOR|           283|
| 2017-12-30T11:00:00Z|       1832|PRESENTATION|           284|
| 2017-12-30T11:00:00Z|       1832|        PART|           288|
| 2017-12-30T11:00:00Z|       1832|  COMMERCIAL|           289|
| 2017-12-30T11:00:00Z|       1832|  COMMERCIAL|           290|
| 2018-01-23T11:00:00Z|       3459|PRESENTATION|           295|
| 2018-01-23T11:00:00Z|       3459|   PROMOTION|           296|
| 2018-01-23T11:00:00Z|       3459|     SPONSOR|           297|
| 2018-01-23T11:00:00Z|       3459|        PART|           298|
| 2018-01-23T11:00:00Z|       3459|     SPONSOR|           299|
| 2018-01-23T11:00:00Z|       3459|PRESENTATION|           300|
| 2018-01-23T11:00:00Z|       3459|        PART|           301|
| 2018-01-23T11:00:00Z|       3459|  COMMERCIAL|           302|
| 2018-02-01T11:00:00Z|       7834|        PART|           305|
| 2018-02-01T11:00:00Z|       7834|        PART|           306|
| 2018-02-01T11:00:00Z|       7834|  COMMERCIAL|           307|
| 2018-02-01T11:00:00Z|       7834|PRESENTATION|           308|
| 2018-02-01T11:00:00Z|       7834|   PROMOTION|           309|
| 2018-02-01T11:00:00Z|       7834|     SPONSOR|           310|
+---------------------+-----------+------------+--------------+
```

Expected Output :

```scala
 +---------------------+-----------+------------+--------------+----------------+
 |event_start_date_time|service_key|  event_type|event_sequence|interval_id     |
 +---------------------+-----------+------------+--------------+----------------+
 | 2017-12-30T11:00:00Z|       1832|     SPONSOR|           280|               1|
 | 2017-12-30T11:00:00Z|       1832|        PART|           281|               1|
 | 2017-12-30T11:00:00Z|       1832|     SPONSOR|           283|               2|
 | 2017-12-30T11:00:00Z|       1832|PRESENTATION|           284|               2|
 | 2017-12-30T11:00:00Z|       1832|        PART|           288|               2|
 | 2017-12-30T11:00:00Z|       1832|  COMMERCIAL|           289|               3|
 | 2017-12-30T11:00:00Z|       1832|  COMMERCIAL|           290|               3|
 | 2018-01-23T11:00:00Z|       1832|PRESENTATION|           295|               1|
 | 2018-01-23T11:00:00Z|       1832|   PROMOTION|           296|               1|
 | 2018-01-23T11:00:00Z|       1832|     SPONSOR|           297|               1|
 | 2018-01-23T11:00:00Z|       1832|        PART|           298|               1|
 | 2018-01-23T11:00:00Z|       1832|     SPONSOR|           299|               2|
 | 2018-01-23T11:00:00Z|       1832|PRESENTATION|           300|               2|
 | 2018-01-23T11:00:00Z|       1832|        PART|           301|               2|
 | 2018-01-23T11:00:00Z|       1832|  COMMERCIAL|           302|               3|
 | 2018-02-01T11:00:00Z|       7834|        PART|           305|               1|
 | 2018-02-01T11:00:00Z|       7834|        PART|           306|               2|
 | 2018-02-01T11:00:00Z|       7834|  COMMERCIAL|           307|               3|
 | 2018-02-01T11:00:00Z|       7834|PRESENTATION|           308|               3|
 | 2018-02-01T11:00:00Z|       7834|   PROMOTION|           309|               3|
 | 2018-02-01T11:00:00Z|       7834|     SPONSOR|           310|               3|
+---------------------+-----------+------------+--------------+----------------+
```

I tried this logic using RDD

My code :

```scala
val loc = "/data/logs/transmission"
val adf =sqlContext.read.avro(loc)
val bdf = adf.withColumn("transmission_logs_concat_attributes", concat(adf("service_key"),adf("event_start_date_time"))).withColumn("event_sequence", col("event_sequence").cast("int"))
val df = bdf.select("transmission_logs_concat_attributes","event_start_date_time","service_key","event_type","event_sequence")
 val orderedDF = df.orderBy("transmission_logs_concat_attributes","event_sequence")
 val dataRDD = orderedDF.rdd.groupBy(row => row.getAs[String]("transmission_logs_concat_attributes"))
 val mappedRDD = dataRDD.map(elem => elem._2.toSeq.sortBy(elem => elem.getAs[Int]("event_sequence")))
 val intervalRDD = mappedRDD.map(rowList => addGroupingIntervalId(rowList))


   def addGroupingIntervalId(rowList: Seq[Row]): Seq[Row] = {
   var incrementer =1
   rowList.map(row => row.getAs[String]("event_type") match {
   case "PART" => Row.fromSeq(row.toSeq ++ Seq(updateIncrementId(incrementer,"PART")))
   case _ => Row.fromSeq(row.toSeq ++ Seq(updateIncrementId(incrementer,"OTHER")))
 })
}

 def updateIncrementId(i:Int,eventType:String) : Int = {

   var updatedIncrementer = i
   if(i == 1 && eventType == "PART" || eventType == "OTHER" ) {
   updatedIncrementer = i
   updatedIncrementer
   }

  else if(i != 1 && eventType ==  "OTHER") {
  updatedIncrementer= i
  updatedIncrementer
  }
  else if(i != 1 && eventType ==  "PART") {
  updatedIncrementer =i+1
   i
  }
 else {
   updatedIncrementer
   }

 }
```

The output I got is below , but it is incorrect

```scala
 List([18322017-12-31T03:00:00Z,2017-12-31T03:00:00Z,1832,IDENT,1213,1], [18322017-12-31T03:00:00Z,2017-12-31T03:00:00Z,1832,SPONSOR,1215,1], [18322017-12-31T03:00:00Z,2017-12-31T03:00:00Z,1832,OTHER,1216,1], [18322017-12-31T03:00:00Z,2017-12-31T03:00:00Z,1832,PART,1217,1], [18322017-12-31T03:00:00Z,2017-12-31T03:00:00Z,1832,OTHER,1218,1], [18322017-12-31T03:00:00Z,2017-12-31T03:00:00Z,1832,SPONSOR,1219,1], [18322017-12-31T03:00:00Z,2017-12-31T03:00:00Z,1832,PRESENTATION,1220,1], [18322017-12-31T03:00:00Z,2017-12-31T03:00:00Z,1832,COMMERCIAL,1221,1], [18322017-12-31T03:00:00Z,2017-12-31T03:00:00Z,1832,COMMERCIAL,1222,1], [18322017-12-31T03:00:00Z,2017-12-31T03:00:00Z,1832,COMMERCIAL,1223,1], [18322017-12-31T03:00:00Z,2017-12-31T03:00:00Z,1832,COMMERCIAL,1224,1], [18322017-12-31T03:00:00Z,2017-12-31T03:00:00Z,1832,COMMERCIAL,1225,1], [18322017-12-31T03:00:00Z,2017-12-31T03:00:00Z,1832,COMMERCIAL,1226,1], [18322017-12-31T03:00:00Z,2017-12-31T03:00:00Z,1832,COMMERCIAL,1227,1], [18322017-12-31T03:00:00Z,2017-12-31T03:00:00Z,1832,COMMERCIAL,1228,1], [18322017-12-31T03:00:00Z,2017-12-31T03:00:00Z,1832,COMMERCIAL,1229,1], [18322017-12-31T03:00:00Z,2017-12-31T03:00:00Z,1832,COMMERCIAL,1230,1], [18322017-12-31T03:00:00Z,2017-12-31T03:00:00Z,1832,PRESENTATION,1231,1], [18322017-12-31T03:00:00Z,2017-12-31T03:00:00Z,1832,PROMOTION,1232,1], [18322017-12-31T03:00:00Z,2017-12-31T03:00:00Z,1832,SPONSOR,1233,1], [18322017-12-31T03:00:00Z,2017-12-31T03:00:00Z,1832,OTHER,1234,1], [18322017-12-31T03:00:00Z,2017-12-31T03:00:00Z,1832,PART,1235,1], [18322017-12-31T03:00:00Z,2017-12-31T03:00:00Z,1832,OTHER,1236,1], [18322017-12-31T03:00:00Z,2017-12-31T03:00:00Z,1832,SPONSOR,1237,1], [18322017-12-31T03:00:00Z,2017-12-31T03:00:00Z,1832,PRESENTATION,1238,1], [18322017-12-31T03:00:00Z,2017-12-31T03:00:00Z,1832,PROMOTION,1239,1])
```

Please help me on adjusting the code logic to get the correct expected result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a problem for window functions:

```scala
import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.Window
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

val w = Window
  .partitionBy($"event_start_date_time", $"service_key")
  .orderBy($"event_sequence")

val interval_id = sum((lag($"event_type", 1, "PART").over(w) === "PART").cast("long")).over(w)
```

With data:

```scala
val df = Seq(
  ("2017-12-30T11:00:00Z","1832","SPONSOR",280),
  ("2017-12-30T11:00:00Z","1832","PART",281),
  ("2017-12-30T11:00:00Z","1832","SPONSOR",283),
  ("2017-12-30T11:00:00Z","1832","PRESENTATION",284),
  ("2017-12-30T11:00:00Z","1832","PART",288),
  ("2017-12-30T11:00:00Z","1832","COMMERCIAL",289),
  ("2017-12-30T11:00:00Z","1832","COMMERCIAL",290),
  ("2018-01-23T11:00:00Z","3459","PRESENTATION",295),
  ("2018-01-23T11:00:00Z","3459","PROMOTION",296),
  ("2018-01-23T11:00:00Z","3459","SPONSOR",297),
  ("2018-01-23T11:00:00Z","3459","PART",298),
  ("2018-01-23T11:00:00Z","3459","SPONSOR",299),
  ("2018-01-23T11:00:00Z","3459","PRESENTATION",300),
  ("2018-01-23T11:00:00Z","3459","PART",301),
  ("2018-01-23T11:00:00Z","3459","COMMERCIAL",302),
  ("2018-02-01T11:00:00Z","7834","PART",305),
  ("2018-02-01T11:00:00Z","7834","PART",306),
  ("2018-02-01T11:00:00Z","7834","COMMERCIAL",307),
  ("2018-02-01T11:00:00Z","7834","PRESENTATION",308),
  ("2018-02-01T11:00:00Z","7834","PROMOTION",309),
  ("2018-02-01T11:00:00Z","7834","SPONSOR",310)
).toDF("event_start_date_time", "service_key", "event_type", "event_sequence")
```

The result is:

```scala
df.withColumn("interval_id", interval_id).show(30, false)
// +---------------------+-----------+------------+--------------+-----------+     
// |event_start_date_time|service_key|event_type  |event_sequence|interval_id|
// +---------------------+-----------+------------+--------------+-----------+
// |2018-02-01T11:00:00Z |7834       |PART        |305           |1          |
// |2018-02-01T11:00:00Z |7834       |PART        |306           |2          |
// |2018-02-01T11:00:00Z |7834       |COMMERCIAL  |307           |3          |
// |2018-02-01T11:00:00Z |7834       |PRESENTATION|308           |3          |
// |2018-02-01T11:00:00Z |7834       |PROMOTION   |309           |3          |
// |2018-02-01T11:00:00Z |7834       |SPONSOR     |310           |3          |
// |2018-01-23T11:00:00Z |3459       |PRESENTATION|295           |1          |
// |2018-01-23T11:00:00Z |3459       |PROMOTION   |296           |1          |
// |2018-01-23T11:00:00Z |3459       |SPONSOR     |297           |1          |
// |2018-01-23T11:00:00Z |3459       |PART        |298           |1          |
// |2018-01-23T11:00:00Z |3459       |SPONSOR     |299           |2          |
// |2018-01-23T11:00:00Z |3459       |PRESENTATION|300           |2          |
// |2018-01-23T11:00:00Z |3459       |PART        |301           |2          |
// |2018-01-23T11:00:00Z |3459       |COMMERCIAL  |302           |3          |
// |2017-12-30T11:00:00Z |1832       |SPONSOR     |280           |1          |
// |2017-12-30T11:00:00Z |1832       |PART        |281           |1          |
// |2017-12-30T11:00:00Z |1832       |SPONSOR     |283           |2          |
// |2017-12-30T11:00:00Z |1832       |PRESENTATION|284           |2          |
// |2017-12-30T11:00:00Z |1832       |PART        |288           |2          |
// |2017-12-30T11:00:00Z |1832       |COMMERCIAL  |289           |3          |
// |2017-12-30T11:00:00Z |1832       |COMMERCIAL  |290           |3          |
// +---------------------+-----------+------------+--------------+-----------+
```

Comment: It works, I need to understand more about this lag function to spark 1.5  ,Thanks much , you saved the whole day of research

Comment: It works for small input , when I try with very big file I get the below exception 18/02/05 16:02:04 WARN scheduler.TaskSetManager: Lost task 34.0 in stage 645.0 (TID 20356, cldnode01.prod.bigdata.bskyb.com): java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.spark.unsafe.types.UTF8String cannot be cast to java.lang.Long
 at scala.runtime.BoxesRunTime.unboxToLong(BoxesRunTime.java:110)
 at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.BaseGenericInternalRow$class.getLong(rows.scala:41)
 at

Comment: How to tell based on the fraction of stack trace, but you either hit a Spark bug, or you cluster just cannot handle such amount of data (it is expensive requirement) and it is only a symptom. In both cases, it is nothing that we can resolve here.